# Azure - What roles are required to create a free SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, active-directory

I was recently added as a user in another owner's Active Directory on Azure. However, it appears I do not have the permissions needed to create an SQL Database under the Free License.  It also appears that I do not have any roles. Is there a set of instructions I can give to the owner so I can get the needed access/roles to create, manage and develop a Free SQL Database, SQL-Server or otherwise on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You minimally need to be a [Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) on some Azure Resource Group.